# db2_exec caracteres especiales

Tags: sql, db2

Intento realizar una consulta a una base de datos db2 y existen algunas columnas con "Ñ" que son claves primarias, por lo que las debo incluir.
El problema se crea cuando se ejecta db2_exec

> Warning: db2_exec(): Statement Execute Failed in Despliega_Tabla.php
>   on line 190  Failed Query:22021:No puede realizarse la conversiÃ³n de
>   caracteres. SQLCODE=-330

Alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 0):

Se debía realizar un cambio en las confiduraciones del zend server y en los valores del sistema. 
CCSID : 819
Id Lenguaje : C
Sistema CCSID : 284